# High availability using cloud load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, high-availability

I am looking for the best way to achieve high availability for my organizations applications.  Since they contain sensitive information, the applications must reside inside my organizations data centers.

I was thinking of using Google load balancing to direct requests to my servers, but I don't think they can be pointed at external servers, just Google VMs.  Does anyone know if that's true?

My other thought was that I could use Google load balancing to point to Google VMs running Nginx and have that load balance between my data centers.  Does anyone know if that is feasible?  Under this scenario, can I terminate SSL on my servers, or does it have to terminate at the Google VM?

Comment: I can't directly answer your questions about googles load balancing, but in regard to using nginx, you should be able to do that; you can certainly do it with haproxy, as I've done it myself.  Nginx should not really be any different.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are correct:  You cannot use Google Cloud's [Network load-balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) with external servers.

You could do your second option, but I'd strongly suggest you reconsider the approach:  too many moving parts, and for what benefit?   If a server goes down you lose session state anyway, so maybe it'd be better for you to use DNS load balancing instead.

FYI I use Google LoadBalancing and AutoScaling, it works pretty good, but not perfect (frequent 502 burps), which is probably why it's still in "Beta".

Comment: One concern that I had with my 2nd option is where ssl is terminated.  I think I read some where in the docs that it would terminate at the VM, and I need it to terminate back at my servers.